# Installing QGIS 2.16 together with QGIS 2.14 standalone?

Tags: qgis, installation, windows-7, qgis-2.16

I have just downloaded and installed `QGIS Standalone Installer Version 2.14 (64 bit)`from [this site](http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html) for a Windows 7 OS. It seems that version 2.16 has been installed too! When I launch a QGIS project, the 2.16 version is loaded automatically... I would like to work with the new LTR version only. My issue is that I can't find any folder related to 2.16 version on my computer (C:\) and version 2.14 only appears in the *Add / Remove Programs* control panel; therefore I'm not able to uninstall it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the version that is started by double-clicking on projects, navigate to

```
 C:\Program files\QGIS Essen\apps\qgis-ltr\bin\
```

double-click on qgis.reg, and .qgs files will be opened with the ltr version. Afterwards, you can safely delete the apps\qgis path where 2.16.0 has been installed.

Answer (score 2):

I think this recently fixed issue is related to your post:

[Long term release installer 2.14 installs 2.16 and makes 2.16 default version](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/15278)

Comment: The issue is supposed to be "*Fixed in the latest standalone installers (2.14.4-2 / 2.16.0-3)*" but only 2.14.4-1 standalone installer seems to be available on the official website... Is there another repository where I could get the latest exe file?

Comment: Change the site language to German, and you will get version 2.14.4-2.

Comment: Thanks @AndreJ! I thought all sites were updated at the same time... The french one still doesn't offer the 2.14 LTR version.

Comment: You have been impatient. Today all three offer the same.